# Converting an array of bytes (uint8_t) into an array of words (uint16_t) and vice versa

Tags: c++, performance, image-processing, visual-c++

I have a very time critical piece of code to optimize which does convert arrays of bytes into arrays of words and vice versa. The operation is used to convert between 8 and 16-bit image data.

The array is qword aligned and large enough to store the result.

The conversion from byte to word requires a multiplication with 257 (so 0 is converted to 0 and 255 gets 65535)

A simple solution could be

```
void simpleBytesToWords(void *ptr, int pixelCount)
{
    for (int i = pixelCount - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(ptr)[i] = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(ptr)[i] * 0x101;
}
```

I also tried to increase performance by converting 4 bytes at once to make use of 64 bit registers:

```
void bytesToWords(void *ptr, int pixelCount)
{
    const auto fastCount = pixelCount / 4;

    if (fastCount > 0)
    {
        for (int f = fastCount-1; f >= 0; --f)
        {
            auto bytes = uint64_t{ reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(ptr)[f] };

            auto r2 = uint64_t{ bytes & 0xFF };
            bytes <<= 8;
            r2 |= bytes & 0xFF0000;
            bytes <<= 8;
            r2 |= bytes & 0xFF00000000ull;
            bytes <<= 8;
            r2 |= bytes & 0xFF000000000000ull;

            r2 *= 0x101;

            reinterpret_cast<uint64_t*>(ptr)[f] = r2; 
        }
    }

    if (pixelCount % 4)
    {
        auto source = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(ptr);
        auto target = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(ptr);

        for (int i = fastCount * 4; i < pixelCount; ++i)
        {
            target[i] = (source[i] << 8) | source[i];
        }
    }

}
```

It is working and it is slightly faster than the simple solution.

The other direction (words to bytes) is done with this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++i)
    reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(bufferPtr)[i] = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(bufferPtr)[i] / 256;
```

I have been searching for compiler intrinsics to speed up this conversion, but have not found anything usefull. Are there any other ways to improve the performance of this conversion?

Comment: If you are only ever going to want to do this on x86 then you might consider using SIMD (SSE/AVX).

Comment: This does not work. You are overwriting input data before you read it. This will only work correctly if you loop backwards, start at the back of the array.

Comment: To speed up the code, don’t multiply, simply copy the one byte to the lower and upper byte of the output word.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: You are right. I wrote this code on stackoverflow because I only had the "optimized" version. I think it is fixed now.
Copying did take longer than multiplying because you need to [copy, shift, or] or you have to seperate memory writes.

Comment: Use bit shift, not divide.  The compiler can't optimize it for you, because they are not equivalent after integral promotion kicks in and converts both operands to `signed int`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Bitshifting instead of multiplying improved my test code throughput from 150% (compared to the reference implementation) to over 800%. So `a = (uint16_t{b} << 8) | b` is about 5 times faster than `a = b * 0x101`. Tank you - I did not expect this.

Comment: Strange: for word to dword the multiplication (* 0x10001) is two times faster than the shifting !?

Comment: Perhaps multiplying is simpler for the compiler to grok and auto-vectorize?  Otherwise scalar `imul` has 1 per clock throughput and costs 1 uop, but shift + OR costs multiple uops, and you probably bottleneck on the front-end. 
 Also, SSE4.2 has an instruction for this, `pmovzxbw`, or even byte to dword directly with `pmovzxbd`.  Or AVX2 can do the same thing for vectors twice as wide (producing a 32-byte output vector per instruction).  Use Intel's intrinsics for this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried two things after having compiled your code (I just renamed `bytesToWords()`, which is now `groupedBytesToWords()` below):

- Test of your two functions: they don't produce the same results. With `simpleBytesToWords()` I end up with a zero-filled array. With `groupedBytesToWords()` I end up with an alternance of valid results and zeros.
- Without changing them, assuming a bugfix wouldn't change their complexity, I tried a third one I wrote and that uses a precalculated `uint8_t` -> `uint16_t` table that has to be built initially:

Here is this table. It's a small one as it only has 255 entries, one per possible `uint8_t`:

```
// Build a precalculation table for each possible uint8_t -> uint16_t conversion 
const size_t sizeTable(std::numeric_limits<uint8_t>::max());

uint16_t * precalc_table = new uint16_t[sizeTable];

for (uint16_t i = 0; i < sizeTable; ++i)
{
    precalc_table[i] = i * 0x101;
}
```

The third function I tried is below:

```
void hopefullyFastBytesToWords(uint16_t *ptr, size_t pixelCount, uint16_t const * precalc_table)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = precalc_table[ptr[i]];
    }
}
```

I tested it of course, and the results it produces look according to the description you made in your original post. This function is called by passing the same parameters as we do for the two other functions, plus the precalculated conversion table:

```
hopefullyFastBytesToWords(buffer, sizeBuf, precalc_table);
```

Then I did some comparisons, using a 500000000 `uint16_t` long array, initially filled with random `uint8_t` values. Here is an example using the `simpleBytesToWords()` you wrote:

```
fillBuffer(buffer, sizeBuf);
begin = clock();
simpleBytesToWords(buffer, sizeBuf);
end = clock();
std::cout << "simpleBytesToWords(): " << (double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << std::endl;
```

I obtained the following results (you'll see I used a small and slow laptop). Here are three example but they are all consistantly producing values of similar magnitude:

```
$ Sandbox.exe
simpleBytesToWords(): 0.681
groupedBytesToWords(): 1.2
hopefullyFastBytesToWords(): 0.461

$ Sandbox.exe
simpleBytesToWords(): 0.737
groupedBytesToWords(): 1.251
hopefullyFastBytesToWords(): 0.414

$ Sandbox.exe
simpleBytesToWords(): 0.582
groupedBytesToWords(): 1.173
hopefullyFastBytesToWords(): 0.436
```

This doesn't stand for a real actual and valid benchmark of course, but it shows that your "grouped" function is slower on my machine, which is not in accordance with the results you obtained. It also shows than precalculating the multiplications instead of casting/multiplying on the fly helps a little.

Comment: I am so sorry for the error in `simpleBytesToWords`. Wrote it directly on stackoverflow and did not iterate in the right direction X-(. Should be correct now.

Comment: @AndreasH.That's no problem. Iterating forward or backward has roughly the same complexity, so execution time comparisons above still apply. And this was the question finally.

Comment: I've tested your table method on my Pentium G4650 (home PC) an its a little bit slower than the simpleBytesToWords. The G4650 did a max of 2.4 GPixel/Second with any method. This is exactly the DDR clock. I'll try it again on my office PC with a i7-6700. (Visual C++ Optimization settings are at maximum)

Comment: @AndreasH.It's interesting to see these ivergences depending on the test environments. Well, if it doesn't help I'll withdraw this answer. Bits shifting, as Ben Voigt suggested comment, is an intersting approach to explore.

Comment: Bitshifting instead of multiplying improved my test code from 150% (compared to the reference implementation) to over 800%. So `a = (uint16_t{b} << 8) | b` is about 5 times faster than `a = b * 0x101`. I did not expect this.

Comment: @AndreasH Hey that's great! So I'll withdraw this answer. The strange thing is that using a table should be even faster than shifting. Are you sure you didn't include the table computation, just done once at startup time, in your bench?

Comment: I did the table calculation in a lambda and used a global std::array for the table (which should be optimized away). My initialization looked like `static const auto WordTable = []() { auto result = std::array<uint16_t, 256>{}; ...; return result; };`. The function itself used a `const auto tbl = WordTable.data();` as first statement.

Comment: I really would like to accept your answert to appreciate your work but I am afraid it I cannot because it does not really solve the problem. So I just gave it an upvote. However, we can still leave it here for future reference.

Comment: @AndreasH. That's kind of you, but I agree with you: this shouldn't be the accepted answer as it does not solve the problem you are facing. That's life :-) Thanks a lot!